# Why this syntax is wrong? Can not use GET and SET for more than a property in a line

Tags: c#, declaration, field

I have to define a lot of fields, and I can't do it like:

```
public double d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6 {get;set;} //does not work
```

Instead I have to do

```
public double d1 { get; set; } public double d2 { get; set; } //and so on
```

but on private fields we have:

```
private double d1, d2, d3, d4 = 0; //Works
```

I cant get it why it is not working. Maybe somone can explain please? is there a way around?

**Update:**
It seems that a lot of copy pasting made me to screw my knowledge and forget the difference between Fields & Properties. Anyway in the first line I meant everything should be Properties

Comment: I think the third line of code only sets d4 as 0 and the others would remain null. I think you should try doing double d1 {get; set;}, d2{get; set;}... and so on. :)

Comment: Since they're value types they'd actually 0.0 anyway, but good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Properties are function calls, you cannot give them a default value this way. Use the class constructor or another function instead.

Here is a quick tip to type faster in Visual Studio. Type fields :

```
public int a;
public int b;
public int c;
public int d;
```

Then type `{ get; set; }` and cut it to the clipboard CTRL+X

Select all the semicolons up to down maintaining **ALT key and left mouse pressed together**

Then paste CTRL+V : TA-DA !

```
public int a { get; set; }
public int b { get; set; }
public int c { get; set; }
public int d { get; set; }
```

Comment: WoW I am working with PC haha about 20 years :D I did not know about holding ALT while selecting!!!

Comment: Or use the code snippets - type prop and then tab twice - should automagically expand to a property.

Comment: You can also use alt + drag to spread your cursor to multiple rows and type in all of them at once. (obviously changing the variable names afterwards)

Answer (score 7):

On the first line there would be an ambiguity; do you want `d1` to `d5` to be properties or fields (which are 2 different things). To avoid this problem it simply isn't allowed.

---

Note the below:

```
double field;
double property {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 4):

From C# Language Specification

1.6.7.2 Properties

> Properties are a natural extension of fields. Both are named members with associated types, and the syntax for accessing
>   fields and properties is the same. **However, unlike fields, properties
>   do not denote storage locations**. Instead, properties have accessors
>   that specify the statements to be executed when their values are read
>   or written.

Answer (score 3):

Fields (`int x`) and properties (`int X { get; set; }`) are different things.  You can't mix the two types of declarations in the same statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way Microsoft designed the syntax...
It's like asking why I leave an apple out of the window it falls. answer: gravity power works that way...
**=)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel happy that those statements work:

```
private double d1, d2, d3, d4 = 0;
```

I think the code is harder to read. Personally I prefer "one variable - one line", so I have no trouble that

```
public double d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6 {get;set;}
```

don't work.

It is the syntax of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry friend, you gotta do a lot of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

type propf and then tap tap or prop and tap tap.
think thats the easiest way.
I use this alot my self.

with propf you will get

```
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
```

and with prop you will get

```
    public int MyProperty { get; set; };
```